# Reveal page at specific point

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reveal a page from a specific point in this case the (div:content) further down the page.

Desired effect will have the red block at the top, however scrolling down will reveal the blue block above

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/cr8uj/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    block
</div>

<div class="content">
    content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.block {
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.content {
        background: red;
        margin-top: 300px;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: "loading" implies inserting content from an external resource, such as an AJAX call.

Comment: could you specify what do you really want? what i understood is: when the page reveals, you can see the red div at the top. when you start scrolling down, the blue div appears at the top (covering the red block) and it stays at the top as a fixed element. Is that you want?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "load" to "reveal" as it makes much more sense.

Comment: Are you looking for a sticky menu of sorts?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for: **scrollTop**

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

> Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar for each of the
>   set of matched elements.

Example:
`$('body').scrollTo('#YourDiv');`

There is a question related to this: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

---

A good library: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples/responsive/index.html

Other options:

What you need is the JavaScript *window.scrollTo* method

```
window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos)
```

Insert the *div* position in there.

Or use the JQuery method ScrollTo, [see an example here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$(...).scrollTo( 'div:eq(YourDiv)', 800 );
```

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle with the suggestion but seems I can't scroll when over the blue block

Comment: @Rob that is due cause you are using  `width: 100%; height: 100%`, so, there is nothing to scroll, but if you make it larger that 100%, then you the scroll will appear.

Comment: @Rob I found another library, check this out: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples/responsive/index.html